# Listview divider after each item

Tags: android, listview, divider

i can't understand, why divider don't comes after every item? It shows only after last item! I really don't know what to do.

I am parsing some information by using Jsoup.

What i have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GHSn.png)

My Listview

```
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="#B9B9B9"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ListView all you need to do is add android:divider tag, like this:

```
 <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/listView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"
     android:divider="#FFCC00"
     android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>
```

Also Optionally you can set divider height with android:dividerHeight tag.